# Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, xubuntu, windows, bios

Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04 on a Huawei machine

Hi guys!

I am trying to erase my Windows and replace it with Ubuntu. I watched this video about how to do it: https://youtu.be/lqSL_s4put8

But when I click the Restart button in order to boot from the USB, I got a notification stating that the Boot: FAILED

And then my BIOS menu opened..why this happened? what should I do now?

I was advised to disable the Secure Boot and try that way, which is what I did but unfortunately no progress...BIOS opens again..please help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8SRP.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by BIOS open?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CD/DVD drive it's easier to burn a Ubuntu CD from an ISO image and use that to install - https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

USBs are a bit unreliable. UNetBootin is the best option in my humble opinion https://unetbootin.org/

Insert your medium (USB or CD). Restart, and press whatever function key you need to enter the BIOS, probably F2. Go to 'Boot Options' and move the medium you are using to the top of the list. Exit the BIOS and you should be good to go.

The Ubuntu installation medium will give you the option to wipe the disk